# Get 1 month results

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql, while-loop

I want to get 1 month results. How is can i do?
'20220601 07:00' - '20220601 18:50' hour is importent.

[image]

```
DECLARE @i int = 0

WHILE @i < 31
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1
    (Select Top 1 Tarih  
     FROM  PersonelTransaction 
     Where PersonelId=175 
     AND   CompanyId=1 
     AND   Tarih >= DATEADD(DAY,@i + 1,'20220601 07:00') 
     AND   Tarih <= DATEADD(DAY,@i + 1,'20220601 18:50') 
     AND   (Aktif = '0' OR Aktif = '2') 
     AND   TerminalId not IN (9, 10, 11, 12)  
     AND Yon = 2)
END
```

Comment: Using a loop in sql is not recommended, can you explain what you are trying to achieve here ? Best would be if you add some sample data and expected outcome, and please do not put the sample data as image but as text

Comment: could you please provide some sample data and desired output. It looks like cursor is not required here

Comment: So what is wrong with your query? Do you have an error? Do you get incorrect results? What *are* your expected results? What *is* your actual question?

Comment: What is the significant of  this date range `20220601 07:00' - '20220601 18:50`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not :

```
SELECT *  
FROM   PersonelTransaction 
WHERE  PersonelId=175 
       AND   CompanyId=1 
       AND   Tarih BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(2022, 5, 1) AND 
                           DATEFROMPARTS(2022, 5, 31)
       AND   Aktif IN (0, 2) 
       AND   TerminalId not IN (9, 10, 11, 12)  
       AND   Yon = 2
```

?

Comment: A staff member will enter and exit continuously throughout the day, and the first entry and last exit information we need.
Since there are shift workers, there must be a hour condition.

Comment: @SüleymanSülün given you haven't provided any sample data and desired results,you leave us guessing as to your actual requirements.